# Use divergence theorem to calculate surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Use the divergence theorem to calculate $\int _TF\cdot n\:dS\:$ when $F(x,y,z)=x^3i+y^3j+z^2k$ and $T$ is the surface area to the half sphere given by $x^2+y^2+z^2\le1$ , $z\ge0$. The normal vector should point out of the half sphere.

I have managed to set up the integral in two different ways,

The first one being:
$\int _0^{2\pi}\:\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\:\int _0^1\:\left(\left(3\left(\rho ^2-\rho ^2\cdot \:cos^2\left(\phi \right)\right)\right)+2\cdot \rho \cdot \:cos\left(\phi \right)\right)\rho ^2sin\left(\phi \right)d\rho \:d\phi \:d\theta $

The second one being: $\int _0^{2\pi}\:\int _0^1\:\int _0^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\:3r^2+2z\:dz\:r\:dr\:d\theta $

Both of the integrals gives the answer, $\frac{13\pi }{10}$, which is wrong. The correct answer according to my book is, $\frac{6\pi }{5}$.

Comment: $T$ as defined is a solid, not a surface.  Is it possible you mean $\int_{\partial T} F \cdot n \, dS$?

Comment: @fourierwho I am not sure to be honest. It says T is the surface area to the region given in the problem above.

Comment: Maybe the problem you were given has a typo and it should be $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \color{red}{=} 1$?  Or it should say something like "$T$ is the surface $\color{red}{\text{of the solid}}$ given by..."?  Eh.

Comment: @tilper I think the problem is written exactly as in my book, just translated to English. Not sure if it makes a difference?

Comment: I got $\frac{13 \pi}{10}$ as well.

Comment: @fourierwho I have an "exercise book" with exercises and answers only, and an "answer book" which contains answers (and its calculation) to some hand picked exercises.  I realized now that the "answer book" says the answer is 13pi/10, while the exercise book says it is 6pi/5. I guess it must be wrong in the exercise book then.